# How to obtain specific HTTP session variable for Apache Access Log?

Tags: java, apache, jsp, jboss

I am using JBoss (Wildfly) to test out logging functionality.

Basically I have the following `index.jsp` file:

```
<%
    //First: Set the Session Variable
    HttpSession sess = request.getSession(true);
    sess.setAttribute("springUserPrincipal", "foo");
%>
<html>
    <h1>Welcome <%=sess.getAttribute("springUserPrincipal")%></h1>
</html>
```

When the webpage loads, it says "Welcome foo" as one would expect.

However, when trying to format the log pattern for the access.log file, I'm having some trouble retrieving the actual "springUserPrincipal" variable for the log file.

This is what I try:
`<access-log pattern="%h %u &quot;%{s,springUserPrincipal}&quot; %t '%r' %s %b" prefix="access"/>`

And when I start up the JBoss Instance, the following error appears on the console:

`15:26:44,679 ERROR [io.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) UT005017: Unknown variable %{s,springUserPrincipal}`

I am using the token guide that is found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/io.undertow/undertow-core/1.0.0.Beta8/io/undertow/server/handlers/accesslog/AccessLogHandler.java).

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try `%{springUserPrincipal}s` as the format specifier